# c array comparison trouble

Tags: c, arrays

im writing a program that looks if an entered string a palindrome is
im using c, not c++ 
i wrote a function to do this, the string that has been entered gets put into an array called data in the main function.

```
int palindroom(char data) {
length = sizeof(data); //getting the length of the word
for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
    j = length-1-i; //inverting the string
    resstr[i] = data[j]; //
}
if (data = resstr)
    return (1);    //returning result
else return (0); }
```

im getting the c2109 and E0142 error in visual studio but i dont really get what im doeing wrong.
(might be good to know that i just started learning c at school so im a bit new to c)

Comment: `data` is a single `char`, so `data[j]` doesn't make any sense. Also what is `resstr`?

Comment: Also, assuming you'd change `data` to be a `char*`, then `sizeof(data)` will **not** return the size of the array and `data = resstr` is an assignment, not a comparison (not that you can compare the contents `char` arrays using `==`anyway)

Comment: data is an array and so is resstr, forgot to tell this

Comment: @KarsNoordhuis 'data is an array' no, it's not.

Comment: @MartinJames i did define them as global arrays, i just have not included the rest of the code. only the palindrome function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You are passing a character not a word. You need to pass the character array to pass the word.
- To know the length of a null terminated string you would use `strlen()` function.
- To reverse a string you can use `strrev` but you can do simpler things to know if a string is palindrome or not.
- `data = resstr` is an assignment not comparison. And even if it was `==` the comparison wouldn't do what you expect. To compare strimgs you need to use `strcmp()`.

A simpler version of what you want to do:-

---

```
int pal(char *s)
{
    size_t len = strlen(s);
    char *rs = s + len - 1;
    while (s < rs){
        if (*rs != *s)
            return 0;
        s++;
        rs--;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

The logic is in case of palindrome the string reads same forward an dbackward.

For example

ABCBA and reverse of it is same. What we do is

```
ABCBA
|   |
s   rs  <--- same 

ABCBA
 | |
 s rs   <--- same
```

For a nonpalindrome the check would be somethign like this:-

```
ABCDA
|   |
s   rs  <-- same

ABCDA
 | |
 s rs   <-- not same // return 0
```

To help you a bit regarding passing char array.

suppose you read a string like this :-

```
char s[50]; // you will check 49 letter words atmost;

scanf("%49s", s);

if( pal(s) ){
   puts("found a palindrome");
}
else {
   puts("Non-palindrome");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a series of problem with your code.

```
int palindroom(char data)
```

Here **data** expects a single character but you pass a pointer to char to it.

```
length = sizeof(data);
```

The function you need is not sizeof() but strlen().

```
if (data = resstr)
```

Here, first of all '=' is an assignment operator while the operator for comparison is '=='. But, '==' will also not work for strings. You need strcmp() for that.

**Reference :**

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcmp.htm
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm

**Code**

```
int palindroom(char * data) {
    length = strlen(data); //getting the length of the word
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++){
        j = length-1-i; //inverting the string
        resstr[i] = data[j]; //
    }
    if (strcmp(resstr, data) == 0)
        return (1);    //returning result
    else return (0); 
}
```